# Change option text color in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, select, colors

I'm trying to force the text color in the option of a select input and it's working on every browser in the world but guest what, yeah IE still don't give a damn about the color in the stylesheet.

Do you guys know how to force IE to make my text color like I wish

Here's what I expect

[image]

and this is what IE does

[image]

**CSS**

```
#footer .findProduct select{background: transparent; border:0; color:#fff!important; font-weight:700; text-transform: uppercase;  font-family: 'Crimson Text',serif; }
#footer .findProduct select option{color:#000!important; text-transform: uppercase;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Styling selects with css is just a bad idea. It is impossible to get them styled correctly in all browsers. All you can do is mimic the select box with js. There are frameworks and plugins availble. Basicly they will hide the select and replace them with a list or something that acts like a select, and wich you can style completly. In the background they will update the select in sync with the list to still make your form work on submit. You could also do something similar yourself (best to use jQuery), it should not be to hard if you are a bit familiar with it.

I guess the custom arrow button you use in your screenshot is not working eather...

Comment: In reality I would have used the -moz-appearance: none but Firefox can't handle it. So i've just positioned an image over the arrow ;)

Comment: i got that from the outline that stops where the button starts. But what happens if you click the arrow in stead of inside the select box?

Comment: that's my point. Not realy great for ux, is it... I would take my advice and go for the js solution. Or just forget all about styling your select.

Answer (score -1):

Your css rules contradict each other change them to this:

```
#footer .findProduct select{background: transparent; color: #fff; border:0; font-weight:700; text-transform: uppercase;  font-family: 'Crimson Text',serif; }
#footer .findProduct select option{color:#000 !important; text-transform: uppercase;}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dan_barzilay/tJZek/

Comment: No, one is for the default selection and the other are for the options when you click on it. And by doing this, the default selected option is black and must be white

Comment: You don't get it, I want the default to be white and the options to be black like the first image. Now your example is only black in both.

Comment: Which IE version you're using because on IE7, IE8 and IE9 it's black all both of them. And your CSS example, you've only removed the !important on the select... it's pretty much the same as mine I'm using now.